# Как правильно сложить свойства, двух функций конструкторов ?

Tags: javascript

Когда задается оружие герою : "archer._setWeapon(bow);", нужно что бы  добавлялся "_basicDamage" к урону от оружия  в противном случае выводился, только  базовый урон

```js
function Weapon(name, damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
    this._getDamage = function () {
        return this.damage;
    };
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'toString', {
        value: function () {
            return name + ' damage: ' + this._getDamage() + " points";
        }
    });
}
var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20);
var sword = new Weapon('Magic sword, ', 40);
console.log(Object.keys(bow)); // check access to keys
function Unit(basicDamage, type) {
    this._basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this._type = type;
    this._setWeapon = function (weapon) {
        var me = this;
        me.weapon = weapon;
        return me;
    };
    this._getDamage = function () {
        return +this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : 0 + this._basicDamage;
    };
    this.toString = function () {
        return "Type - " + this._type + ", Have weapon -" + this.weapon + "," + ' hero current damage - '
            + this._getDamage() + ' points';
    }
}
function Archer(basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this._type = "archer";

}
var archer = new Archer(30);
archer._setWeapon(bow);
console.log(archer.toString());
```

Comment: Внутри определения `_setWeapon()` добавить строку `this._basicDamage += weapon.damage`? Или я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в двух местах:

1. лишний `+` в условии: `+this.weapon ?`. Так как `weapon` это объект, при приведении к числу он всегда приводится как `NaN`, и выполняется вторая ветка условия.
2. приоритет операций: `cond ? first : last1 + last2` - в этом случае группируются как `cond ? (first) : (last1 + last2)` а не `(cond ? first : last1) + last2`. Для решения нужно просто явно указать скобки.

В итоге получится так:

```js
function Weapon(name, damage) {
  this.name = name;
  this.damage = damage;
  this._getDamage = function() {
    return this.damage;
  };
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'toString', {
    value: function() {
      return name + ' damage: ' + this._getDamage() + " points";
    }
  });
}
var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20);
var sword = new Weapon('Magic sword, ', 40);
console.log(Object.keys(bow)); // check access to keys
function Unit(basicDamage, type) {
  this._basicDamage = basicDamage;
  this._type = type;
  this._setWeapon = function(weapon) {
    var me = this;
    me.weapon = weapon;
    return me;
  };
  this._getDamage = function() {
    return (this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : 0) + this._basicDamage;
  };
  this.toString = function() {
    return "Type - " + this._type + ", Have weapon -" + this.weapon + "," + ' hero current damage - ' +
      this._getDamage() + ' points';
  }
}

function Archer(basicDamage) {
  Unit.apply(this, arguments);
  this._type = "archer";

}
var archer = new Archer(30);
archer._setWeapon(bow);
console.log(archer.toString());
```